# SwiftyJSON convert string array to array not working

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have data as below:

```
data = 
[
"\u65b0\u5317\u5e02\u4e09\u91cd\u5340","\u65b0\u5317\u5e02\u6c38\u548c\u5340",
"\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4e2d\u5c71\u5340","\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4e2d\u6b63\u5340",
"\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4fe1\u7fa9\u5340","\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5357\u6e2f\u5340",
"\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5927\u540c\u5340","\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5927\u5b89\u5340",
"\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u6587\u5c71\u5340","\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u677e\u5c71\u5340",
"\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u842c\u83ef\u5340"
]
```

but when I want to convert it to array, I use the code:

```
data.array
```

it always give me nil, what can I do?

I've also tried `data.arrayValue` and `data.arrayValue.map {$0.stringValue}`

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant here since I don't use SwiftyJSON but the correct format for a hexadecimal value in a swift string is `\u{65b0}`

Comment: what is your `data` type?

Comment: @OlegBaidalka  My data type actually just String only

Comment: @Berlin please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data construct is

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            "\u65b0\u5317\u5e02\u4e09\u91cd\u5340",
            "\u65b0\u5317\u5e02\u6c38\u548c\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4e2d\u5c71\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4e2d\u6b63\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u4fe1\u7fa9\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5357\u6e2f\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5927\u540c\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u5927\u5b89\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u6587\u5c71\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u677e\u5c71\u5340",
            "\u53f0\u5317\u5e02\u842c\u83ef\u5340"
        ]
    }
]
```

Convert JSON into entity meanwhile conform Codable Protocol

```
typealias DistEntity = [Dist]

struct Dist: Codable {
    let data: [String]
}
```

Implementation model layer

```
protocol JSONFetcher: AnyObject {
    func distParser(forResource fileName: String, completionHandler handler: @escaping((Result<DistEntity, Error>) -> ()))
}

class ModelLayer: JSONFetcher {

    enum ParserError: Error {
        case PathNotFound
        case ConvertsObjectError
        case DecoderError
    }

    func distParser(forResource fileName: String, completionHandler handler: @escaping((Result<DistEntity, Error>) -> ())) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") else { return handler(.failure(ParserError.PathNotFound)) }
        guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return handler(.failure(ParserError.ConvertsObjectError)) }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        guard let distEntity: DistEntity = try? decoder.decode(DistEntity.self, from: jsonData) else { return handler(.failure(ParserError.DecoderError)) }
        handler(.success(distEntity))
    }
}
```

Preliminary parse in the interface of business logic layer

```
final class viewModel {

    private var fetcher: JSONFetcher

    init(fetcher: JSONFetcher = ModelLayer()) {
        self.fetcher = fetcher
    }

    private func distParser() {
        self.fetcher.distParser(forResource: "YourJSONFileName") { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let entity):
                print("[Dist Entity]: \(entity)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can't make sure that's useful for your scenario,

If no solve, may you should provide more detail info.